# How I can convert uploaded audio clip into array of byte in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert an audio clip to an array of bytes so I can analyze the audio clip later on. The reason for that is I want to build an algorithm for silence detection in the clip and for visualization using the spectrogram.
In another word, I have the following audio link that is extracted from the upload element:

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/e7bc3aaf-95bc-46c4-aa6f-e76565a4c041
```

is there a way to convert the audio itself (not the link) to an array to analyze it using javascript?

```
someobj.analyze(blob:http://localhost:3000/e7bc3aaf-95bc-46c4-aa6f-e76565a4c041)
```

```
output: [0,0,0 45,32,54,33,55,56,66,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Have you looked into `Response.arrayBuffer()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working to meet my need.  For instance, when I  apply the blow code in my work (no matter the size of the file and the length of the recorded) it always returns an array of 106 elements, which is impossible.

-----
  async function dataURLtoFile(fileUrl) {
    return await new Response(fileUrl).arrayBuffer();
  }
out: ArrayBuffer(106)

Comment: That's not a fetch - you created a new response object that did not make a HTTP query. You need to use `await fetch(url, options)` to get the HTTP Response object for your query. Read up on the `fetch()` API for info

Comment: Thanks, David I solve the problem. I will publish the solution soon.